# Fake access point not showing up as a wireless network

Tags: networking, ruby, wifi

I'm trying to write a fake access point script in ruby; the script is below:

```
require 'packetgen'

def fake_ap
    print 'Making a fake ap...'
    while true
        bssid = 'aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa'
        iface = 'mon0'
        ssid = 'NoWifi'
        broadcast = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
        pkt = PacketGen.gen('RadioTap')
        pkt.add('Dot11::Management', mac1: broadcast, mac2: bssid, mac3: bssid)
        pkt.add('Dot11::Beacon', cap: '0x1114')
        pkt.dot11_beacon.add_element(type: 'SSID', value: ssid)
        pkt.dot11_beacon.add_element(type: 'Rates', value: "\x82\x84\x8b\x96\x24\x30\x48\x6c")
        pkt.dot11_beacon.add_element(type: 'DSset', value: "\x06")
        pkt.dot11_beacon.add_element(type: 'TIM', value: "\x00\x01 \0x00\0x00")
        pkt.calc
        pkt.to_w(iface)
        end
    end

fake_ap
```

[Hexdump of packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkn9F.png)

The program is supposed to send beacon frames; I ran the program (with my wireless card on monitor mode) however it doesn't show up as an access point. It there a problem with my code or something else. The docs for the `packetgen` library are [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/packetgen/PacketGen/Header/Dot11/Management). Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach a hexdump of the actual packet you're transmitting? Also, can you see your transmissions from another WNIC in monitor mode?

Comment: @Spiff I attached the hexdump in a link above, and yes I can see the packets going across the wire on Wireshark